# How to setup nginx server with wildcard DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, wildcard-subdomain

This is about an sample Rails app that uses subdomains. You can access it here: http://rodrigora.com.br. In this app, you can create site and specify one subdomain for it.

> Example:
>
> site: `Google`
>
> subdomain: `gog`
>
> This site should be accessible by http://gog.rodrigora.com.br

But, the app is unreacheable for any subdomain, neither `www`.

---

**DNS server configuration:**

[image: DNS]

**nginx server configuration:**

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  #server_name localhost;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/blog/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }

  # Rails error pages
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /home/ubuntu/apps/blog/current/public;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /home/ubuntu/apps/blog/current/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

**Extra information**: If I access `www.rodrigora.com.br` on browser, Google Chrome show the not found page,but `nginx` logs this line:

```
186.210.71.46 - - [21/Sep/2013:22:08:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"
```

---

**Questions:**

- So, nginx is saying that the `www` subdomain is not there?
- How to configure this app to respond to any subdomain?

---

**Resources:**

[Railscast Subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

[DNS propagation](http://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.rodrigora.com.br)

[Wildcard DNS check](http://www.usefulutilities.com/cgi-bin/checkdns)

Comment: All seems okay [as of now](http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rodrigora.com.br). How did you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the server name as `*.rodrigora.com.br` this will let the nginx server to accept any request with one of this domain subs.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `listen 80 default_server;`?

This might be more what you need. I believe that for server name `_;` is a catch-all.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Yes @Frank, no success.

Comment: Please, stop using rewrite, when a simpler and [efficient solution is available for 301 redirects](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites).